# Refresh token before time out Angular

Tags: angular, token, interceptor

I have to refresh a token, I use an interceptor to do it but it doesn't seem to work. My function is called but the token isn't refreshed when the API returns the HTTP code 401.

**The function of the service**

```
  public getToken(): string {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
    return this.token;
  }
```

Here I post the token I want to refresh

```
refreshToken() {
    console.log(this.token);
    return this.http.post<any>(environment.apiBaseUrl + 'refresh', this.token, httpOptions);
  }
```

**The interceptor**

```
 intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let authReq = req;
    const token = this.tokenService.getToken();

    if (token) {
      authReq = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + token),
      });
    }
    
    return next.handle(authReq).catch((err: any) => {
      console.log(err);
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.log(err.status);
        console.log(err.statusText);
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.tokenService.refreshToken();
        }
      }
      return throwError(err);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `tokenService.refreshToken` you need to store the token somewhere in tokenService for it to be picked up by `this.tokenService.getToken()` in the following request (or retry of you have retry behavior)

Something like:

```
refreshToken() {
    console.log(this.token);
    this.token = this.http.post<any>(environment.apiBaseUrl + 'refresh', this.token, httpOptions);
  }
```