# Correct way to Refresh a token from MSAL before an AJAX call?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, azure, azure-ad-msal

Is there a way to get MSAL to refresh an access token with the refresh token before an AJAX request?

I've set up my code the same as here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect/blob/master/WebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs

```
﻿using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApp.Utils;

namespace WebApp
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            // Custom middleware initialization. This is activated when the code obtained from a code_grant is present in the querystring (&code=<code>).
            app.UseOAuth2CodeRedeemer(
                new OAuth2CodeRedeemerOptions
                {
                    ClientId = AuthenticationConfig.ClientId,
                    ClientSecret = AuthenticationConfig.ClientSecret,
                    RedirectUri = AuthenticationConfig.RedirectUri
                });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    // The `Authority` represents the v2.0 endpoint - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0
                    Authority = AuthenticationConfig.Authority,
                    ClientId = AuthenticationConfig.ClientId,
                    RedirectUri = AuthenticationConfig.RedirectUri,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = AuthenticationConfig.RedirectUri,
                    Scope = AuthenticationConfig.BasicSignInScopes + " Mail.Read", // a basic set of permissions for user sign in & profile access "openid profile offline_access"
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        // In a real application you would use IssuerValidator for additional checks, like making sure the user's organization has signed up for your app.
                        //     IssuerValidator = (issuer, token, tvp) =>
                        //     {
                        //        //if(MyCustomTenantValidation(issuer))
                        //        return issuer;
                        //        //else
                        //        //    throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("Invalid issuer");
                        //    },
                        //NameClaimType = "name",
                    },
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                        RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                    },
                    // Handling SameSite cookie according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/owin-samesite
                    CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(
                                     new SystemWebCookieManager())
                });
        }

        private  Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> arg)
        {
            arg.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("myNewParameter", "its Value");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
        {
            // Upon successful sign in, get the access token & cache it using MSAL
            IConfidentialClientApplication clientApp = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
            AuthenticationResult result = await clientApp.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(new[] { "Mail.Read" }, context.Code).ExecuteAsync();
        }

        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
        {
            notification.HandleResponse();
            notification.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + notification.Exception.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried redirecting the user through a sign in challenge but immediately run into cors issues. I've tried calling aquiretokenAsync() so MSAL will use the refresh token behind the scenes, but this also seems to cause a cors issue. ( If it is something along those lines, where do I call this? Can I do it in an authorize attribute? Or where is the best place?)

I've searched through every stack overflow and Azure github issue I can find, but either can't understand the answer or they seem to be 5 years old and use ADAL not MSAL.

e.g.
[Handle token timeout in Asp.Net MVC when using Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467751/handle-token-timeout-in-asp-net-mvc-when-using-azure-ad)

[Refresh token before time out Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65921066/refresh-token-before-time-out-angular)

https://github.com/azuread/microsoft-identity-web/issues/603

tl;dr

I understand MSAL will automatically refresh internally if I do aquireTokenAsync, but I'm unclear on when or where I can call this function before an AJAX request and without reloading the page.

I'm new to MSAL an OAUTH2 authentication in general and would be really grateful for any explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`acquireTokenSilent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently) method to automatically refresh token for you in MSAL.NET.

> MSAL uses a cache to store tokens based on specific parameters
> including scopes, resource and authority, and will retrieve the token
> from the cache when needed. It also can perform silent renewal of
> those tokens when they have expired. MSAL exposes this functionality
> through the `acquireTokenSilent` method.
>
> `acquireTokenSilent` will look for a valid token in the cache, and if it
> is close to expiring or does not exist, will automatically try to
> refresh it for you. You should use a loginXXXXX or acquireTokenXXXXX
> (interactive) API before this to establish a session with the server.

```
AuthenticationResult result = null;
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

try
{
 result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
        .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
{
 // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilent.
 // This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenInteractive to acquire a token
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

 try
 {
    result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
          .ExecuteAsync();
 }
 catch (MsalException msalex)
 {
    ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
 }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
 return;
}

if (result != null)
{
 string accessToken = result.AccessToken;
 // Use the token
}
```